# Two background colors (Horizontal)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'am wondering If It's possible to have two different colors in the background, expanding 100% with bootstrap, en each side.

Here is a screenshot of what i mean,

[image]

Red on the left side, dark on the right side, expanding 100% for bigger screens. Any easy solutions for this?

Comment: Just curious why this would be required.

Comment: @Paulie_D bad designer i guess? well, problem is, the red area will have 1 box, and darker, 2 boxes. or "col-md-3" as an example. So i don't this gradient would work that well :(

Comment: The divs in the 'content' can have their own bg colors (red/black). The body could have a gradient with a stop at 50% but since it will always be underneath no one will see the join.

Comment: I'd suggest if any of these answers where helpful to you that you accept one, so that if anyone had to find this question in future, they can easily find the solution. Personally I think AndyM provided a great answer :)

Comment: Appreciate that, Rohan. To Lena, is there anything about my answer that you'd like clarification on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. The best way uses pseudo-elements. You'd apply one color to the `<body>`, and the second color to a created `:after` element.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <main>

        <p>This is my first paragraph.</p>

        <p>This is my second paragraph.</p>

        Page continues...
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:rgb(155,155,155);
}

body:after {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:rgb(239,0,0);
    content:"";
}

main {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:white;
    min-height:400px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q66Xn/3/

This answer produces the cleanest code. Disadvantages: Limited IE8 support, no IE7 support. If you need to use those two browsers, then see the next option:

---

Give the `<body>` the same background color of one side, then instead of using :after to create a pseudo-element, we just create a real element.

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="bgleft"></div>

    <main>

        <p>This is my first paragraph.</p>

        <p>This is my second paragraph.</p>

        Page continues...
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:rgb(155,155,155);
}

#bgleft {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:rgb(239,0,0);
}

main {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:white;
    min-height:400px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q66Xn/4/

The produces exactly the same as the first method. The advantage is higher browser compatibility, with a disadvantage of a little bit more code.

---

Finally, you could use a gradient attached to the body. This will give both colors on the single body element, saving extra HTML, but it'll by a nasty set of CSS to support all browsers:

```
body {
    background: rgb(239,0,0); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2VmMDAwMCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjQ0JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2VmMDAwMCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjQ0JSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzliOWI5YiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM5YjliOWIiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(239,0,0) 0%, rgb(239,0,0) 44%, rgb(155,155,155) 44%, rgb(155,155,155) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgb(239,0,0)), color-stop(44%,rgb(239,0,0)), color-stop(44%,rgb(155,155,155)), color-stop(100%,rgb(155,155,155))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(239,0,0) 0%,rgb(239,0,0) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(239,0,0) 0%,rgb(239,0,0) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(239,0,0) 0%,rgb(239,0,0) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgb(239,0,0) 0%,rgb(239,0,0) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 44%,rgb(155,155,155) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ef0000', endColorstr='#9b9b9b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q66Xn/

Disadvantages: Complex CSS which is difficult to easily edit later on.

Answer (score 2):

You will struggle to do this using only bootstrap.
You could achieve the result you are after using linear gradients: http://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/snjkw this would need a fallback for browsers that do not support gradient bgs.

```
body{
  background: #49191a; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #49191a 0%, #49191a 30%, #53cbf1 30%, #53cbf1 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#49191a), color-stop(30%,#49191a), color-stop(30%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#53cbf1)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #49191a 0%,#49191a 30%,#53cbf1 30%,#53cbf1 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #49191a 0%,#49191a 30%,#53cbf1 30%,#53cbf1 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #49191a 0%,#49191a 30%,#53cbf1 30%,#53cbf1 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #49191a 0%,#49191a 30%,#53cbf1 30%,#53cbf1 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#49191a', endColorstr='#53cbf1',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're issue isn't related to bootstrap specific, as Ollie stated.

Some of your options are, using a gradient, or a sliver (a 1px width/height image, which you repeat on which ever axis).

I find using a gradient generator works quite well for most of my new projects I need to startup. I've attached an example for you to try.

**Example**

> http://jsfiddle.net/wLw4r/4/

**Markup**

```
    <body>
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h2 style="color: white">Something</h2>      
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <h2>YOLO</h2>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">Something</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">Something</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">Something</div>   
                <div class="col-md-2">Something</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {

background: rgb(169,3,41); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(169,3,41) 0%, rgb(143,2,34) 26%, rgb(143,2,34) 26%, rgb(0,0,0) 26%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgb(169,3,41)), color-stop(26%,rgb(143,2,34)), color-stop(26%,rgb(143,2,34)), color-stop(26%,rgb(0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(169,3,41) 0%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(0,0,0) 26%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(169,3,41) 0%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(0,0,0) 26%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgb(169,3,41) 0%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(0,0,0) 26%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgb(169,3,41) 0%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(143,2,34) 26%,rgb(0,0,0) 26%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */   

}
```